# Correlation with Pearson possible for Continous - Dummy Variable? Otherwise options?

Tags: correlation, categorical-encoding, pearson-r, boxplot

I assume that I cannot interpret correlation coefficients given by Pearson method for continous - dummy variables. Is this correct?

Which options can I pursue otherwise? Its for the decriptive statistcs part of a paper I am writing. My next gues would be to simply draw boxplots (0 - 1 on the X-axis) and visualize the connection between those two that way. Is this feasible?
Thank you.

Comment: A boxplot is a good option.

Comment: Why not? There's a covariance between the two variables, and each one has a standard deviation. Just calculate the correlation. The sign will be dubious, since coding your indicator variable as 0/1 versus 1/0 is arbitrary, but once you make that decision, the correlation makes sense. It may not be a great way to convey information, but you certainly can calculate it. It will be helpful to discuss why you want to include this value, however.

Comment: Thanks you both!